# django-rest-framework filter returns empty by providing multiple values of the same column

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a table called OP, it has many columns including a column named website which is of string type.
using Django-rest-framwork I want to filter out those rows which is having website=FAO,BD,CD

right now my, if I use `https://...../op/?website=FAO`, returns correct data but If I can't get any data if I put many values like `https://...../op/?website=FAO,CD,BD.`

How can I achieve the result

here is my code and what I tried;

```
class op_filter(FilterSet) :
    
    # website = filters.CharFilter('website')
    website = filters.CharFilter(method='filter_by_website')
    ......
    ......
    
    class Meta :
        model = Op
        fields = ['website',.........]

    def filter_by_website(self , queryset , name , value):
        # I get strings like FAO,CD,BD thats why I split it 
        website_name = set(value.strip().split(','))
        return queryset.filter(website__in=website_name)

class op_ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet) :
    queryset = Op.objects.all().filter()
    serializer_class = op_Serializer
    # permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend , SearchFilter , OrderingFilter]

    filter_class = op_filter
```

how to write my filter function so that it returns the correct data.

> website is a column of OP table

**

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to update the `get_queryset` of your ViewSet ? I know you can use Filter, but it could help identify the problem. Like that :

```
class op_ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet) :
    queryset = Op.objects.all() # No need to put filter here
    serializer_class = op_Serializer
    # permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend , SearchFilter , OrderingFilter]

    def get_queryset(self):
        website_parameter = self.request.query_params.get('website', None)
        if website_parameter is not None:
            website_name = set(website_parameter.strip().split(','))
            return Op.objects.filter(website__in=website_name)
        return Op.objects.all()
```